# How to Tell Twitter "Who's in this photo" using API calls

Tags: twitter

With Twitter: when you manually add a photo to a tweet, a button appears asking "Who's in this photo." You can use that to tag multiple twitter users in that photo. Note that this is separate from a simple @mention in the tweet text itself. Attaching users to the photo does not incur any further character cost from the tweet itself.

Is there a way to accomplish this through API calls?

Presently our custom CMS posts tweets using the "POST media/upload" call followed by the "Post statuses/update" (which includes the id of the media uploaded by the first call).

I cannot find in the Twitter API documentation a parameter or additional call that would allow one to specify users that appear in the photo.

Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have finally determined that it can't be done. Twitter simply hasn't opened this feature up to the API (as of  26 days ago).

Here's the Developer support thread on the subject for future reference.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-new-photo-tagging-feature/13023